# Is self-modifying-at-file-level code possible?

Tags: c

I try to write a C code such that executing its binary `a.out` changes the `a.out` file itself.

For example, I want to write foo.c like:

```
% gcc foo.c
% a.out
Hello world!
% a.out
Bus error
%
```

Comment: Yes, what have you done?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to do in a portable way (the way the executable is structured will be different on every system - ELF vs .exe, amb64 vs ARM), but you can bundle something like libgcc or libclang with your output file which should allow codegeneration + compilation.

Look at the code for the clang executable [here](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/driver/cc1_main.cpp?revision=126577&view=markup) which should give you some good ideas.

What you might do (in pseudo code):

```
string myNewCode("#include <stdio.h>\nint main(int argc, char *argv[]){ printf(\"Bus error\\n\");return 1; }");
var compiler = new Compiler();
var temp_file = new tempFile();
compiler->compile(myNewCode, temp_file);
move_file(temp_file, argv[0]);
```

(secondary edit: having giving this a little more thought, this is completely possible and portable with libclang)

Answer (score 1):

Not portably, no.

In many flavors of Windows, you can't modify the executable of a program being run. This is often highly annoying, even when doing something "more sane" than what you're proposing.

In Linux I think it would be fine, just open `argv[0]` and modify it. Of course if your process was loaded off the path you migth have issues locating the proper file, but there should be some `/sys` entry or something that can lead you (down) to the absolute path.

Comment: `argv[0]` is the program itself? Wow! I only thought it was the name of the program.

Comment: @NlightNFotis It's only the name, he means that to know what to open you need to know the name :)

Comment: @NlightNFotis It is the name of the program. Not sure what you thought I meant. I imagined the OP doing e.g. `open(argv[0], ...)` to open the file that contains the running program for modification.

Comment: Under Linux, `/proc/$pid/exe` is a symlink to the program file.

Comment: Wouldn't another viable way (on Linux) to change the program at runtime be to open `/proc/$pid/mem` and modify it? I'm just asking, never done it myself. I know that you can open `/dev/mem` and modify it, with crashtastic sequences, so I guess it's usage might be the same.

Comment: @unwind As I understood it, he thought `argv[0]` contained the executed program itself as binary data :)

Comment: @Jite Yeah that's what I understood in the beginning. It's morning here and I'm short on coffee you see :D

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead an tried it. The example below works on Linux as per your spec (Beware, this is hacky, non-dynamic code!)

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char str1[]="Hello world!"; //12 chars + \0
//        echo -n "Bus error"| wc -c  # 9 + \0 -- need to pad by 3

int main(int argc, char const * const argv[]){
  puts(str1);
  system("sed 's/Hello world!/Bus error\\x0\\x0\\x0/' a.out -i~\n"
         "rm a.out~\n");
  return 0;
}
```

You can't write to that file in place though (unless you want to bring the app down to a noisy crash). Using `-i~` doesn't write in place, but rather moves the original file to `a.out~`, while creating a modified copy named `a.out`. (The OS continues reading the same file regardless of the name change. Removing/unlinking is also OK -- Linux programs can continue accessing unlinked files if they had opened them (without closing) before the unlinking).